# C# using WCF when sending rows of data from online db to local db to online db

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services, wcf

Good day, i have basically no experience in sending information over the internet, so excuse me if this is a little to DUH for you, i am trying to better my understanding.

What i have is a mysql database hosted somewhere on the WWW which is populated with a web application, i also have a local database stored on my ..local machine, which is populated via a windows form created in C#.
All of the above works like a charm.

What happens is, the web site creates some data in `ONLINE_TABLE_ORDER`.
The local app does some dark magic (based on data in `ONLINE_TABLE_ORDER` and populates `TABLE_1` in the local mysql database, then `TABLE_2` stores a bunch of data based on whats going on in `TABLE_1`.
On the click of a button its time to send ALL the data from `TABLE_2` to `ONLINE_TABLE_STATS` which is the online mysql database and keeps updating the same table for statistical purposes.

What i need to do, is to send the rows of data from `ONLINE_TABLE_ORDER` to the local database, the C# windows form will then automatically pick up the details and populate various controls, when all is said and done the application will then need to send rows of data from `TABLE_2` to `ONLINE_TABLE_STATS` where the web form will then pick up this new data and display it accordingly.

That being said, i now need to figure out how to go about sending all of this.
This is where WCF and web services comes in.(i guess, its what information i have managed to wring out of google).

Now i would like to do this via services to maintain data integrity (local internet is shitty, and could cut out at anytime, so i am hoping that web services can help with that).

Finally, this is where my understanding needs some TLC,

## 1: Can a WCF service form part of my C# application; in that the application pulls data from the web based mysql database and then pushes data back to that database?

## 2: Can a WCF service run by itself from within the local application? or does the server on which the web database is hosted also need a WCF service running?

## 3: Does only the online server need a WCF service running? (create an applet in C#?)

## 4: Is this all overkill and i dont actually need any services when a simple bulk insert statement suffice? (remember shitty internet).

Remember, i would like the service to handle
`ONLINE_TABLE_ORDER` --> `TABLE_2` --> `ONLINE_TABLE_STATS`

No, i am mostly self taught and am really eager to learn more about this, even if it is overkill; as i have been checking out tutorials and blogs, none have actually given me sufficient answers to the above.

Most, deal mainly with application to hosted database but have yet to find one from database to database which is what i am trying to do.
So in closing, if you can help my understanding as well as leave some kick ass links to great reading material, id really appreciate that. If you lovely individuals require anymore information about the how's or why's, leave a comment and ill edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to comunicate from your CSharp app to your online database via web services like you said. So, you need a WCF service hosted online with access to the database (or other kind of service, like an api in the online web site who have access to the databse). Also you need a service client in your CSharp app who comunicates with the online server.

So answering to your numbered questions:

1. A WCF can be hosted in a C# application (called "self hosted service" or something like that) but it does not resolve your problem. Your CSharp app should be client not service.
2. Basically the same answer than before
3. The online server need some kind of service who interacts with the database listening to http request. So, WCF is a good alternative. You can use another kind of web service, like a api service in the web application
4. In MY OPINION i think you need a service who controls security, data transport and a lot of stufs